# Conditional RewriteRule redirection

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a basic rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^facial-moisturizer-spf-15.html /kyoku-facial-moisturizer-spf-15.html [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for a 1-2-1 redirection but I have to redirect both of these:

> /facial-moisturizer-spf-15.html
>
> /moisturisers/facial-moisturizer-spf-15.html

Is there a way I can do that in one line rather than resort to a RewriteCondition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally untested but:

```
RewriteRule ^(moisturisers/)?facial-moisturizer-spf-15.html /kyoku-facial-moisturizer-spf-15.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks - we won't know what the preceeeding segment is - will try that with a wildcard

Comment: Then how about something like `RewriteRule (facial\-moisturizer\-spf\-15\.html)$ /kyoku-$1 [R=301,L]` (again, untested, just off the top of my head)

Comment: Thanks, that produced a loop unfortunately. Tinkering now

Comment: That's right, I guess you could add a `RewriteCond` to avoid the loop (`RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false`), but then again, if your original question was trying to avoid `RewriteCond`s, then that might not work for you. I guess that's some where to start though :-)